# claim-based Authorization for multiple Claims in Asp.net Core

Tags: controller, asp.net-core, authorization, data-annotations, authorize-attribute

Got help from this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies

I tried to create some policies for my actions , but in some actions I want to have multiple policies , and if user has either of them, they can have access to Actions of controller :

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "CanAccessMenu1")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "CanAccessMenu2")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> ActionFroMultiplePolicies([FromBody] ActionRequest request)
        {
//..............
}
```

how can I merge this policies ? can I use something like this?

**[Authorize(Policy = "CanAccessMenu1, CanAccessMenu2")]**

In this case , maybe I need to have some changes in this override functions. But I dont have any idea about that :

```
Protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CanAccessRequirement requirement)
        {
        }
```

Thanks for any help